# How to capture screenshot of UIWebview with all the content?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uikit

I am able to capture the screen shot of the entire webpage (including the off screen content). This is working fine on simulator, but on device it is crashing. Please help me on this, check the code below (`browserView` is the UIWebview).

```
UIImage *screenImage=[[UIImage alloc] init];
UIScrollView *browserScrollableView=[[UIScrollView alloc] init];
browserScrollableView=browserView.scrollView;   
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(browserScrollableView.contentSize);
CGPoint savedContentOffset = browserScrollableView.contentOffset;
CGRect savedFrame = browserScrollableView.frame;

browserScrollableView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
browserScrollableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, browserScrollableView.contentSize.width, browserScrollableView.contentSize.height);

[browserScrollableView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];     
screenImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

browserScrollableView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
browserScrollableView.frame = savedFrame;
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSLog(@"Captured image size is %f X %f",screenImage.size.width,screenImage.size.height);

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469764/rendering-a-uiwebview-into-an-imagecontext

Comment: @AnkitGupta Thank you. This solution wont work in all the cases, because all website's design is not the same. If the webpage doesn't have the body tag and is loading based on some js, then this won't work(if I'm not wrong)

Comment: Yes Anil, you can right,i did not use it,but i was trying to solve your problem, is it work in your case??

Comment: @AnkitGupta I'm not using any specific website/page. Ideally my screenshot should work on all type of pages. My code is working on the simulator perfectly, I'm not getting why it is crashing on device??? :(

Comment: Not directly related to your question but you'd be better off replacing `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(browserScrollableView.contentSize);` with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(browserScrollableView.contentSize, NO, 0.0);` See: [UIKit Function Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html). Also: if you're calling this on background thread that might be the reason for crashing.

Answer (score 6):

```
+ (UIImage*) captureWebView: (UIWebView*)webView {
    // capture webview
    UIImage *img = nil;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(webView.scrollView.contentSize, webView.scrollView.opaque, 0.0);
    {
        CGPoint savedContentOffset = webView.scrollView.contentOffset;
        CGRect savedFrame = webView.scrollView.frame;

        webView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
        webView.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, webView.scrollView.contentSize.width, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);
        [webView.scrollView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        webView.scrollView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
        webView.scrollView.frame = savedFrame;
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using this function and its work for me

```
-(UIImage*)captureScreen:(UIView*) viewToCapture
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewToCapture.bounds.size);
    [viewToCapture.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return viewImage;
}
```

the parameter "viewToCapture" will be your webView.

Comment: I want the hidden/out of bounds content also from the webview, that is the reason I'm using scrollview.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

```
browserScrollableView=browserView.scrollView;
```

Is NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);

Check your device iOS version.

Comment: Can you add more information to explain to the OP what you're suggestion?

Comment: property scrollView for UIWebView is  NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
try to check if browserView respondeToSelector:@selector(scrollView)