# UIWebView to UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I tried to capture image from UIWebView using this method but the image contains only visible area of the screen. How do I capture full content of UIWebView including invisible areas, i.e. the entire web page into one single image?

```
-(UIImage*)captureScreen:(UIView*) viewToCapture{
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewToCapture.bounds.size);
  [viewToCapture.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return viewImage;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT** (from a comment by [Vad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634603/vad))

Solution was to call

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

in the initialization, and

```
[webView sizeToFit]
```

when the page did finish loading.

You are currently capturing only the visible part because you are limiting the image context to what's visible. You should limit it to what's available.

`UIView` has a `scrollView` property that has `contentSize`, telling you what is the size of the web view inside the scroll view. You can use that size to set your image context like this:

```
-(UIImage*)captureScreen:(UIView*) viewToCapture{
    CGSize overallSize = overallSize;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewToCapture.scrollView.contentSize);
    // Save the current bounds
    CGRect tmp = viewToCapture.bounds;
    viewToCapture.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, overallSize.width, overallSize.height);
    // Wait for the view to finish loading.
    // This is not very nice, but it should work. A better approach would be
    // to use a delegate, and run the capturing on the did finish load event.
    while (viewToCapture.loading) {
         [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
    }
    [viewToCapture.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    // Restore the bounds
    viewToCapture.bounds = tmp;
    return viewImage;
}
```

Comment: this partially solved the problem. the resulting image has a correct size but invisible area is all white.

Comment: @Vad I think the problem has to do with the `viewToCapture.layer` then. See if setting the bounds temporarily would fix the issue (see the update).

Comment: I think the problem is that web view does not display all content until you scroll there.

Comment: @Vad You are right, the web view is probably still loading the additional stuff when you call `renderInContext:`. Could you add `NSLog(@"%d", viewToCapture.loading)` and see if it prints `1` or `0`?

Comment: I run a snapshot code when the page is fully done loading. I suspect UIWebView hidden content is not displayed for memory saving reasons until you scroll to those hidden areas. I'll confirm soon.

Comment: @Vad There is a chance that resizing the view may trigger loading again. I am not sure of that, because I do not have access to a setup where I could test this assumption.

Comment: Solution was to call [webView sizeToFit] when page did finish loading and webView.scalesPageToFit = YES; in initialization.

Comment: @Vad Thanks - I added your comment to the text of the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Check this out [Rendering a UIWebView into an ImageContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469764/rendering-a-uiwebview-into-an-imagecontext/21885693#21885693)

or just use this :) :

```
    (UIImage*) imageFromWebview:(UIWebView*) webview{

//store the original framesize to put it back after the snapshot
CGRect originalFrame = webview.frame;

//get the width and height of webpage using js (you might need to use another call, this doesn't work always)
int webViewHeight = [[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"] integerValue];
int webViewWidth = [[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollWidth;"] integerValue];

//set the webview's frames to match the size of the page
[webview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, webViewWidth, webViewHeight)];

//make the snapshot
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(webview.frame.size, false, 0.0);
[webview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//set the webview's frame to the original size
[webview setFrame:originalFrame];

//and VOILA :)
return image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** :  New answer from me with tested code.

Add below `method` to `capture` `UIWebView`into `UIImage`. It will also capture `unvisible area` as well.

```
- (UIImage*)webviewToImage:(UIWebView*)webView
{
  int currentWebViewHeight = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
  int scrollByY = webView.frame.size.height;

  [webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

  NSMutableArray* images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  CGRect screenRect = webView.frame;

  int pages = currentWebViewHeight/scrollByY;
  if (currentWebViewHeight%scrollByY > 0) {
      pages ++;
  } 

  for (int i = 0; i< pages; i++)
  {
    if (i == pages-1) {
        if (pages>1)
            screenRect.size.height = currentWebViewHeight - scrollByY;
    }

    if (IS_RETINA)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screenRect.size, NO, 0);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( screenRect.size );
    if ([webView.layer respondsToSelector:@selector(setContentsScale:)]) {
        webView.layer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    }
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);

    [webView.layer renderInContext:ctx];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if (i == 0)
    {
        scrollByY = webView.frame.size.height;
    }
    else
    {
        scrollByY += webView.frame.size.height;
    }
    [webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, scrollByY)];
    [images addObject:newImage];
  }

  [webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

  UIImage *resultImage;

  if(images.count > 1) {
    //join all images together..
    CGSize size;
    for(int i=0;i<images.count;i++) {

        size.width = MAX(size.width, ((UIImage*)[images objectAtIndex:i]).size.width );
        size.height += ((UIImage*)[images objectAtIndex:i]).size.height;
    }

    if (IS_RETINA)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    if ([webView.layer respondsToSelector:@selector(setContentsScale:)]) {
        webView.layer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    }
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);

    int y=0;
    for(int i=0;i<images.count;i++) {

        UIImage* img = [images objectAtIndex:i];
        [img drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,y)];
        y += img.size.height;
    }

    resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  } else {

    resultImage = [images objectAtIndex:0];
  }
  [images removeAllObjects];
  return resultImage;
}
```

Also add these `macro` for checking if `iOS` is `retina` display

```
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] && ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0))
```

Comment: This results in visible content being stretched on the image and invisible content is still all white/blank.

Comment: I tested a very long page, but app crash when  if(images.count > 1) {~ UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0); due to memory pressure. It's good idea of segmenting, but I guess momory pressure is occurred when aggregate images. Do you have any solution?